# "X has/have joined"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which are correct?

> 1 has joined the channel.
>
> 1 have joined the channel.
>
> 5 has joined the channel.
>
> 5 have joined the channel.

Comment: Are `1` and `5` user IDs, or counts of the number of users joining the channel, or just what?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP provided "X" as the subject, which could be anybody or anything, singular or plural. The answer must therefore be: "it depends".

Comment: Now, I see! The question should be written: **One has / have joined the channel.** and  **Five has / have joined the channel.** The numbers looked like a numbered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `has` for singular, `have` for plural and zero. And for numbers less than 10, write out as words. So:

- One has joined the channel.
- Five have joined the channel.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to avoid the helping verb entirely. Since the message is likely to be displayed at the moment the joining occurs (or very soon thereafter), you could just use " joined the channel", e.g. "1 joined the channel", "5 joined the channel".